# matplotlib python quivers not showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have a contour plot that looks great. I want to plot quiver arrows (wind direction) over top of the wind speed contour plot. However when I try to do this with the code below I don't get any errors but the quivers don't show up. Any ideas why? Does it have something to do with my time xaxis?

```
#Contour plot of wind speeds
time_index = np.arange(start_date,end_date,dt.timedelta(minutes=10) )
height = np.arange(30,310,10)
cs = plt.contourf(time_index,height,wspd_sodar.transpose()) 

yy = np.arange(30,310,10)
print np.shape(yy)
xx = np.arange(1, 145)
print np.shape(xx)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(xx,yy)
print np.shape(X)
print np.shape(Y)
print np.shape(u)
print np.shape(v)

plt.quiver(X,Y,u,v,scale=1)
plt.show()

(28L,)
(144L,)
(28L, 144L)
(28L, 144L)
(28L, 144L)
(28L, 144L)
```

Comment: "Does it have something to do with my time xaxis?" Probably, as those are completely different units (not sure about the underlying unit; may be Unix time, thus seconds since 1970). You may need to transform `X` into time as well. (It also doesn't make physically sense, to overplot something that doesn't have the same axis units.)

Comment: meshgrid doesn't work with time axis so I transformed the x in the contour plot to be np.arange(1,145) same as I am using for the quiver and it still isn't showing up but I don't get any errors...This is my biggest confusion. If I use plt.barbs instead they show up but just as a bunch of circles at the points!

Comment: I don't have your data, but I have no problem overplotting the quivers. So it may very depend on the values of `u` and `v`. Your quivers might be too small or too big to see, for example.

Comment: thanks the above code works